# can i use 'input' with type 'time' to display hours instead of minutes?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

It is possible to manage an `input` with type `time` to display only hours, not minutes.

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="heure_seance" class="col-md-4 control-label">Heure : </label>
     <div class="col-md-6">
          <input id="heure_seance" type="time" step='60' class="form-control" name="heure_seance" required>
     </div>
</div>
```

I need to use Javascript or it is possible with an HTML attribute?

I need to do this because on my database, time stored are entire hours, we don't store minutes.

Thank's for help!

Comment: Are you unable to use third-party libraries?

Comment: @EleazarEnrique Yes I can.

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

But you can create custom input, and hide html input, then use JS to feel input value from custom input. You will still have to send to the server side values with minutes, but you can strip the minutes there

Comment: @NikolaMitic yes I have to use JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either disable the input or set it as read-only to avoid unexpected entered text from the user.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js" ></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker3'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
                    format: 'HH'
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank's it seems to works. Just a note, why when I choose a hour with the "select", another "select" with hour from 00 to 23 appears?

Comment: It's just to make easier the user's life.  I mean, imagine the first select shows 13, the user should hit ten times to reach to 23, instead, the bootstrap date time picker provides you a way to select directly the hour.   I think you can disable that behaviour.  Go and read a little more of documentation about date time picker :-).

Comment: Ok so it's not a "bug", it is a desired behavior. Thank's a lot!